# Epic creation fails due to custom fields

Tags: excel, jira-rest-api, vba

I'm using Excel-VBA and trying to create an epic having two custom fields (Epic-Name and Budget) but somehow it doesn't work. Creating a task without the custom fields works fine.
Here's the VBA (but I don't think that there is really an issue with

```
Public Function CreateEpic(ByVal summary As String, ByVal description As String, ByVal project As String, ByVal budget As String, ByVal dueDate As String) As String
    Dim issueType As String
    issueType = "Epic"

    Dim text As String
    text = "{""fields"": {""project"":{ ""key"": """ & project & """},""summary"": """ & summary & """,""description"": """ & description & """,""issuetype"": {""name"": """ & issueType & """},""customfield_12335"":""" & budget & """, ""duedate"":""" & dueDate & """,""customfield_12932"":""" & summary & """}}"
    Dim resp As Object
    Set resp = HttpRequest("POST", "/rest/api/latest/issue", text, True, True)
    MsgBox (text)
    CreateEpic = resp("key")
End Function
```

Here's the JSON (output from the messagebox)

```
{
    "fields": 
    {
        "project":{
            "key": "PROJTEST"
        },
        "summary": "testepic1",
        "description": "testepic01",
        "issuetype": {
            "name": "Epic"
        },
        "customfield_12335":"100h",
        "duedate":"2020-11-1",
        "customfield_12932":"testepic1"
    }
}
```

The error response tells me that there's an issue with the two custom fields but I don't get the point.

[image: error]

Comment: So where is the error?

Comment: The question becomes better and better with every update. On which line is the error?

Comment: whats in `resp("errorMessages")` ? does it contain detailed descriptions of the errors?

Comment: resp("errorMessages") is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The code works, it was just pure stupidity (wrong ids of custom fields)